# Accessing files with invalid names in Windows

Tags: macos, winapi, filenames, createfile, shared-directory

I'm running Windows 7 in a VirtualBox on an OS X 10.8 host. The host has a shared folder with a file named `>>>FILE<<<` inside. Apparently, OS X itself has no problem with such file names. Unfortunately, I can't seem to open this files in Windows 7 because of the `<`s and `>`s in the name.
In C, this call fails:

```
CreateFileW(
    L"\\\\VBOXSVR\\ft1\\>>>FILE<<<",
    GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL
    );
```

`GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` (123). If I change the file name into `FILE`, I get a valid handle and everything is fine.

Is there a known way in Windows to access those files with invalid characters in their names? Supposing a productive environment with no direct write access to the host's file system.

Comment: Does the remote file system provide short filenames? If so, you may be able to access the file using it's short name.

Comment: @JonathanPotter your idea is good, but no, the file system doesn't support short file names and VirtualBox doesn't share them. That may work with an NTFS volume folder shared on a real network with the proper driver. The short file name would look like `___FIL~1`.

Answer (score 2):

@jcophenha's answer was on the right track.  However, if you read [the page that @jcopenha linked to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#win32_file_namespaces), it states that the `\\?\` prefix is for local paths only.  You have to use the `\\?\UNC\` prefix instead for UNC paths, eg:

```
L"\\\\?\\UNC\\VBOXSVR\\ft1\\>>>FILE<<<"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that doesn't seem to work either. It's frustrating.

Comment: If `\\?\UNC\server\share` does not work, then you are out of luck. The remote file needs to be renamed to something that is more cross-platform compatible (or at least have a symbolic link created that maps to the real file internally and is cross-platform accessible).

Comment: @Remy The problem is that both `<` and `>` are reserved characters.

Comment: If you read the linked article, the purpose of the `\\?\ ` and `\\?\UNC\ ` prefixes is to turn off parsing, which include ignoring reserved characters.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` characters are not allowed to be used in a Windows file name. And so that file cannot be opened under Win32.

The [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx#naming_conventions) documentation lists the following reserved characters:

> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)

Windows differs significantly in this area from *nix systems. On *nix there are typically no such OS enforced limitations on the characters that can be used in a file. As a friend of mine once discovered when he tried to delete a file named `*` and suffered the most unfortunate consequences.

Now, it is conceivable that these limitations do not apply when using the native API. You could try and open the file with [`NtCreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432380.aspx). That may just work!

Comment: I'm afraid you may be right. `NtCreateFile` didn't help, I could only open the file after stripping away `<` and `>` from the name. Strangely, other forbidden characters like the pipe `|` are unproblematic.